# Xml parsing and itext

Tags: html, pdf, fonts, xml-parsing, itext

Just wanted to know if it is possible to change the font,color,font size while parsing html to pdf using xmlWorker.parser
Currently I am able to parse whatever I have given as the input.So I wanted to change the font,font size, font color etc if possible.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `CSS` style and add it to your HTML code. The CSS style will be applied according the priority given below where no 4 is the higher priority.

1)Browser default
2)External style sheet
3)Internal style sheet
4)Inline style

Example:

```
document.open();
String finall=  "<style>h1{color:orange;} </style><body><h1>This is a Demo</h1></body>";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(finall.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter,document, is);
document.close();
```

In the Example Orange color will be set to the header.